# What is the relationship between Ezra's scroll and the Aleppo/Leningrad codeces?

Tags: torah-reading, mesorah-tradition, biblical-criticism, ezra-the-scribe, biblical-history

I'm a little bit confused. If Ezra re-established a singular text to the Torah, how is it that we have the Aleppo Codex and the Leningrad Codex and three different scribal traditions for Ashkenaz, Sefard, and Temani? How/when did this happen??

Comment: Scribes who err live in every generation...

Comment: To flesh out Harel’s comment. We’re taking about a period of well over 1000 years from when Ezra wrote his scroll to when these codices were written. Plenty of time for errors in transmission to have crept in.